# How can I report a percentage of the total count in the detail of a crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to get the total count of employee ids so that I can use it as the basis for a percentage in my report.  I'd like my report to look like this:

```
Types                 With Email  
Customer    20%       15%
Vendor      40%       80%
Employees   40%       75%  
Total People: 100
```

In my view I have the employee id, type and email address.  I can get the count and the first percentage (percentage of customers, vendors and employees).  What I'm have trouble with is the percentage of customers or vendors with email address.  I've tried using formula fields and summaries, but haven't gotten too far with them.  Can anyone point me in a direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a formula to calculate email-address presence:

```
//{@has_email}
If Isnull({employee.email}) Then
  0
Else
 1
```

It doesn't need to be added to the canvas.

Create a formula to calculate the % total:

```
//{@email %}

// summarize number of email address for a given type
Local Numbervar Total := Sum({@has_email}, {employee.type});

If Total <> 0 Then
  Total / Count({employee.id}, {employee.type}) * 100
```

Add to group header or footer and format with %.